# Get "No render output node in scene" when trying to render object in blender

Tags: node-editor, error

Looking for solutions to this error all I could find was people saying to add a composite node, or turn off compositing in post processing, but if I add a composite node to the nodes (there were no nodes because I made an object I am trying to render not working with nodes) it just renders a black screen, if I turn off compositing in post processing it renders a yellow and black textured screen. I am very new to blender and was watching a tutorial that said to render the object I tried and got this error.

Comment: There is not enough info to help. Which tutorial were you following? What renderer are you using? Does opening a new .blend and hiting `F12` render the default cube as expected? Did you have any nodes connected to the render output node to provide information for it to render? There are a lot of things that can be changed, without knowing what you were doing, your asking everyone else to make random guesses.

Comment: So you are using Cycles? Are you trying to do Compositing? What is the World material set to? Have you tried adding a test material? What is your lighting situation?